# My bar chart does not appear on screen. How can I fix that?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to teach myself how to plot a bar chart using matplotlib (within a web application), where the x-axis will have kinds of cancer medication side effects, and the y-axis will have percentages of occurrence of each of those side effects. 
On the web application's index page, I have a select menu, where I ask the user to select a type of cancer from the "drop-down list". Upon choosing "breast cancer", and clicking "submit" (which I have created an html file for), I expect the bar chart I discussed above to appear on screen. However, no bar chart at all shows on my screen. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the python code:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
np.random.seed()
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, 
request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, 
InternalServerError
import sqlite3


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

db = SQL("sqlite:///cancermeds.db")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method=="POST":
        selection = request.form.get("cancerlist")
        if selection == "breast cancer":
            #db.execute used to extract info I will use to make 
            #list of keys (for x-axis) and list of values(for y- 
            #axis). Info extracted from table in SQLite3 database. 
            rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM 'breast cancer'")
            for row in rows:
                keys = list(row.keys())
                del keys[16:19]
                print(keys)
                values = list(row.values())
                del values[16:19]
                print(values)

                fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,6))
                plt.bar(keys, values, width=0.5)
                plt.xlabel("Side Effects")
                plt.ylabel("Percentages of Occurence of Side 
    Effects")
                plt.title("Bar Chart showing Side Effects of Breast 
Cancer Medication(s) With Their Corrresponding Percentages Of 
Occurence")
                plt.legend()
                plt.show()

        return render_template("breastcancer.html")

    else:
        return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is everything in my terminal:

```
~/environment/justforme/ $ 
~/environment/justforme/ $ FLAKS RUN
bash: FLAKS: command not found
~/environment/justforme/ $ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "application.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on https://808d061b-7cdd-4348-ab06-3ede74c26f12- 
ide.cs50.xyz:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.133.245 - - [03/Aug/2019 19:13:30] "GET / 
HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.133.245 - - [03/Aug/2019 19:13:30] "GET 
/static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 404 -
DEBUG:cs50:SELECT * FROM 'breast cancer'
['diarrhea %', 'neutropenia %', 'nausea %', 'abdominal pain %', 
'infections %', 'fatigue %', 'anemia %', 'leukopenia %', 'decreased 
appetite %', 'vomiting %', 'headache %', 'alopecia %', 
'thrombocytopenia %', 'peripheral neuropathy %', 'hepatotoxicity 
%', 'cardiac side effects %']
[86, 41, 39, 29, 39, 40, 28, 21, 24, 28, 20, 16, 16, 0, 1, 0]
WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in 
legend.
['diarrhea %', 'neutropenia %', 'nausea %', 'abdominal pain %', 
'infections %', 'fatigue %', 'anemia %', 'leukopenia %', 'decreased 
appetite %', 'vomiting %', 'headache %', 'alopecia %', 
'thrombocytopenia %', 'peripheral neuropathy %', 'hepatotoxicity 
%', 'cardiac side effects %']
[27, 85, 30, 0, 24, 59, 33, 0, 36, 36, 14, 50, 68, 48, 36, 3]
WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in 
legend.
['diarrhea %', 'neutropenia %', 'nausea %', 'abdominal pain %', 
'infections %', 'fatigue %', 'anemia %', 'leukopenia %', 'decreased 
appetite %', 'vomiting %', 'headache %', 'alopecia %', 
'thrombocytopenia %', 'peripheral neuropathy %', 'hepatotoxicity 
%', 'cardiac side effects %']
[24, 8, 40, 19, 10, 50, 14, 1, 0, 19, 28, 0, 31, 32, 0.3, 1.8]
WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in 
legend.
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.133.245 - - [03/Aug/2019 19:13:34] "POST / 
HTTP/1.0" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.133.245 - - [03/Aug/2019 19:13:34] "GET 
/static/styles.css HTTP/1.0" 404 -
```

Being a beginner, please excuse any potentially very basic mistakes that I've made. Thank you!

Comment: Does anything appear on the screen? Like an empty window?

Comment: to display image on webpage you have to save it in file jpg or png in folder `static` and use `<img src="/static/your_file.jpg">` in HTML.

Comment: And you don't have to use `plt.show()` because it will not show it on webpage. It may show only in window on monitor connected directly to web server (if it uses GUI), but not in window on client's monitor or in client's web browser.

Comment: use `print(len(rows))` to see how many results you get. If it display 0 (zero) then it will not run code which create plot.

Comment: Terminal shows warning `WARNING:matplotlib.legend:No handles with labels found to put in legend.` so it may have problem with legend. Try code without legend.

Comment: @brentertainer nothing appears at all on the screen. not even an empty screen.

Comment: @furas thank you for your help! Theoretically I would want to build this in a way where a client can view the bar chart as well. Perhaps I would need to use something other than matplotlib then..

Comment: @JohnAbdelmalek I've never used flask before, so I'm speculating. Maybe it's turning on matplotlib's interactive mode? Add `import matplotlib as mpl`. Then in the first few lines of the function, add two lines: (1) `print(mpl.is_interactive())` and (2) `plt.ioff()`.

Comment: @JohnAbdelmalek And maybe before `plt.show()`, add a line to do a `plt.save('debug.png')` and see if that file is made.

Comment: with any other tool you would have to do the same - save in file and send HTML with `<img>`. With matplot you have to use only `plt.save('static/image.png')` to get plot. And then you have to send HTML with `<img src="static/image.png">`

Comment: using `plt.save('static/image.png')` you can get only static image. Using JavaScript libraries you can get interactive plot in HTML - [mpld3 (Matplotlib + D3.js)](https://mpld3.github.io/), [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/), [plotly](https://plot.ly/), or even dashboad [dash (plotly+flask)](https://plot.ly/dash/) - See: [Bokeh vs Dash — Which is the Best Dashboard Framework for Python?](https://blog.sicara.com/bokeh-dash-best-dashboard-framework-python-shiny-alternative-c5b576375f7f?gi=f5a3dfa2746)

Comment: @furas I adjusted the code as you suggested and I got a long traceback. Here's the final part of it (along with the INFO line):                                                                 
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/justforme/application.py", line 50, in index
    plt.save('debug.png')
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'save'
INFO:werkzeug:192.168.143.110 - - [03/Aug/2019 23:21:42] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 500 -

Comment: @furas i do want the bar chart to be interactive. I'll have a look at the links you provided. Thank you.

Comment: I had to check it - it has to be plt.savefig('static/image.png').

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example which save plot in file and use `<img src="/static/image.png">` in HTML to display it.

```
from flask import Flask
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    keys = [1,2,3,4]
    values = [1,4,2,3]

    plt.bar(keys, values, width=0.5)

    plt.xlabel("Side Effects")
    plt.ylabel("Percentages of Occurence of Side Effects")
    plt.title("Bar Chart showing Side Effects of Breast \
Cancer Medication(s) With Their Corrresponding Percentages Of \
Occurence")
    #plt.legend()

    if not os.path.exists('static'):
        os.makedirs('static')
    plt.savefig('static/image.png')

    return '''<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body><img src="/static/image.png"></body>
</html>'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

Minimal example which use [mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/index.html) to generate interactive plot.

At start it has only tools: home(reset), move, resize.

```
from flask import Flask
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    keys = [1,2,3,4]
    values = [1,4,2,3]

    ax = plt.bar(keys, values, width=0.5)

    plt.xlabel("Side Effects")
    plt.ylabel("Percentages of Occurence of Side Effects")
    plt.title("Bar Chart showing Side Effects of Breast \
Cancer Medication(s) With Their Corrresponding Percentages Of \
Occurence")
    #plt.legend()

    fig = ax[0].figure

    plt_html = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)

    return '''<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>''' + plt_html + '''</body>
</html>'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

Minimal example using [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) but it creates static image.

```
from flask import Flask
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    keys = [1,2,3,4]
    values = [1,4,2,3]

    sns.barplot(keys, values)

    plt.xlabel("Side Effects")
    plt.ylabel("Percentages of Occurence of Side Effects")
    plt.title("Bar Chart showing Side Effects of Breast \
Cancer Medication(s) With Their Corrresponding Percentages Of \
Occurence")
    #plt.legend()

    if not os.path.exists('static'):
        os.makedirs('static')

    plt.savefig('static/image.png')

    return '''<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body><img src="/static/image.png"></body>
</html>'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: for some reason when i tried to import mpld3, I got this:                                              
    File "/home/ubuntu/environment/justforme/application.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mpld3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpld3'

Comment: you have to install `mpld3`

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you, furas.